# Prevent Orchestration step from being executed in silent token acquisition

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

In my SignUp SignIn policy, I have a step where it push information to a RESTful api.
I want that to be executed whenever a user creates an account or sign in.

But I don't want my service to be spammed all the time an app request a silent token (via MSAL `acquireTokenSilent`)

I'm having a hard time understanding what does `<IncludeInSso>` means.

#### Step

```xml
        <OrchestrationStep Order="13" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="GetAccessToken" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SecureREST-AccessToken" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <OrchestrationStep Order="14" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="false">
              <Value>bearerToken</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="AddOrUpdateB2CIdentities" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AddB2C-Account" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
```

#### AddB2C-Account

```xml
        <TechnicalProfile Id="AddB2C-Account">
          <DisplayName>Add to service</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.RestfulProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="ServiceUrl">https://api.com</Item>
            <Item Key="SendClaimsIn">Body</Item>
            <Item Key="AuthenticationType">Bearer</Item>
            <Item Key="UseClaimAsBearerToken">bearerToken</Item>
            <Item Key="AllowInsecureAuthInProduction">false</Item>
            <Item Key="ClaimUsedForRequestPayload">requestBody</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <IncludeInSso>false</IncludeInSso>
          <InputClaimsTransformations>
            ...
          </InputClaimsTransformations>
          <InputClaims>
            ...
          </InputClaims>
        </TechnicalProfile>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignore `includeInSSO`.
Add this session management technical profile to your rest api technical profile:

```xml
...
   </OutputClaims>
   <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-AAD" />
 </TechnicalProfile>
```

Comment: What will it do?

Comment: Since SM-AAD is registered as session management at sign in, when the policy runs in SSO mode, any technical profiles using SM-AAD are skipped when called upon.

Comment: It works! While we are at it, what does exactly `IncludeInSSO` do?